# Gene sequence and DNA

Tags: molecular-biology, dna-sequencing

can anyone help me with this?

It shows two gene sequences for a sheep and a goat.

```
   5’------C C T G A G G A G C A T G T T------3’
   3’------G G A C T C C T C G T A C A A------5’
               5         6         7         8        9
   5’------C C T G A G G G G C A T G T T------3’
   3’------G G A C T C C C C G T A C A A------5’
               5         6         7         8        9
```

I hope u can see it.

number 1 = goat 
number 2 =sheep

1. what differences are there between the two gene sequences?
2. Decide the amino acids 5-9 for both gene sequence?

Comment: Look at the differences in the nucleotide sequences, and how those differences may change translation.

Comment: This question looks like it is from a homework assignment. What have you done to try to solve this problem on your own?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Well, as for question one, the goat has a AT meanwhile the sheep has a GC (under number 6) That may mean that there's a change in the sequence of the amino acid? Or is that thinking wrong?................. as for question 2) I find this difficult. I mean I have a table to see the amino acids, but what should i exactly do?

Comment: You're right. A change in nucleotide sequence 'may' change the amino acid sequence. To find out, use a standard translation table (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_codon_table) to see if a different amino acid results from the difference in codons. To translate, replace each three consecutive nucleotides (codons) with the amino acid in the table.

Comment: Amino acids can have different properties (ex. polarity) that can affect protein folding. If you find a difference in amino acids between the goat and the sheep, look up how the properties of the amino acids differ. If the properties are very different, then the resulting protein may have a different structure, and therefore may have a different function.

Comment: For translating, keep in mind that real sequences may be read by transcriptases in 1 of 3 different reading frames at a time. For each codon, you look at 3 nucleotides, but you may get a different amino acid depending on where you start.

Comment: Thank you indeed. I used the translate-table.  Now, I have to answer what difference there're between the enzyms of the organisms? How should I find that out?

Comment: As I mentioned in a previous comment, different amino acid properties can change the structure of a resulting protein, or enzyme in this case. The wiki page show some of the important amino acid properties. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amino_acid

Comment: Thank you. Now, when I'm going to use my "translate-table" to see which amino acids it's, let's take the goat, should I take the gen sequence from 5' to 3' or that from 3' to 5'  (i need to make the dna to rna)  thx

Comment: I recommend reading this article: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22085/

Comment: Thank you indeed. The part with the difference between the enzyms of the organisms: I have translated my bases into amino acids, but now, when I have to find the difference, should I look at both amino acids from the goat and sheep and compare them? What should I focus on when I compare them? I find it difficult to find the difference between both enzyms.... Thx!

Comment: There is a one amino acid change, GAG encodes glutamate and GGG encode Glycine. the change from glutamate to glycine is a fairly substantial one, both in terms of polarity and also sterics, that likely effects the secondary structure of the polypeptide.